# MongoDb Sharding between replica and standalone server

Tags: mongodb, sharding

So i got a replica set with three servers and a standalone server .
I have enabled sharding between them.

I inserted more data on replica primary server using "rockmongo".

But the chunks are not divided yet and they are still on my replica server

I got more than 50k records so my size in db folder is more than 65M.
the output of sh.status() is

```
        --- Sharding Status --- 
sharding version: {
"_id" : 1,
"version" : 3,
"minCompatibleVersion" : 3,
"currentVersion" : 4,
"clusterId" : ObjectId("534ab99817bb6815bff6bd47")
}
 shards:
{  "_id" : "rsName",  "host" : "rsName/dhruvil-Inspiron-3521:22017,dhruvil-Inspiron-3521:25017,dhruvil-Inspiron-3521:27001" }
{  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "dhruvil-Inspiron-3521:27917" }
databases:
{  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
{  "_id" : "zips",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "rsName" }
    zips.zip
        shard key: { "state" : 1 }
        chunks:
            rsName  1
        { "state" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "state" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rsName Timestamp(1, 0)
```

Any thoughts about what i am doing wrong???

Do we insert data on sharded servers in some other way than normal?

Comment: Measuring the size of the DB folder is not a good method measuring the amount of data within the collection.

What does db.collection.stats() show?

Comment: I solved it ,apparently deleting all records and inserting through mongos server give you an even distribution which does not happen if you have data lying around before sharding enabled